# MongoDB projection query, filter field in matching element of inner array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, database, nosql

I have a document that contains an array. Like so:

```js
"_id" : ObjectId("55101f81e4b07caf8554b9b1"),
"myId" : "1222222",
"isDelayed" : false,
"status" : "BALLS",
"yellow" : false,
"white" : true,
"people" : [ 
    {
        "peopleId" : 222222,
        "bc" : 0,
        "status" : "live",
        "fc" : 1,
        "tc": 4,
        "rc": "yellow" 

    }, 
    {
        "peopleId" : 33312,
        "bc" : 0,
        "status" : "live",
        "fc" : 1,
        "tc": 4,
        "rc": "yellow" 

    }, 
  ...
```

I have a mongo query like below, in the collection `mycoll`, if `myId=1.222` and in the people array if `people.peopleId=1123` it returns the first match:

```js
db.getCollection('mycoll').find(
    {myId:'1.222',
        people: { $elemMatch: { peopleId: 1123 }
                 }
    },{"people.$": 1 }).pretty();
```

The result includes all fields in the people entry from the array:

```js
"people" : [ 
        {
            "peopleId" : 1122,
            "bc" : 0,
            "status" : "live",
            "fc" : 1,
            "tc": 4,
            "rc": "yellow" 

        },
```

How do I filter the reply that it only returns the desired field from the **matching** entry in the inner array, say `"status"`? I can generate a filter for the outer document but not a field in an array element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using aggregation. What you need to do is:

1. Match the documents with the desired `myId`.
2. Unwind the `people` arrays so that there is one document per subdocument inside `people`.
3. Match the specified `peopleId`.
4. Project fields as desired.

```js
db.mycoll.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "myId": "1.222"} },
    { "$unwind": "$people" },
    { "$match": { "people.peopleId": 1123 }},
    { "$project": { "peopleId": "$people.peopleId",
                    "status": "$people.status" }
    }
]).pretty();
```

Answer (score 1):

Mongo [$elemMatch in projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) used in projection to find out specific field in your case `status` below query return only `status` field

```
db.collectionName.find({"myId":"1222222"},{"people":{"$elemMatch":{"peopleId":33312}},"people.status":1}).pretty()
```

Comment: Hi @yogesh, yes but this will return 'status' for all elements of the array instead of just the matching one

Comment: @user1843591 I think you should misplaced some thing, this shows me exact matching result `status` result as below
`{"_id" : ObjectId("55101f81e4b07caf8554b9b1"),"people" : [{"status" : "live"}]}`

Comment: you're right, my apologies, it 'looked' like my attempt at it but i didn't actually try it out. thank you for your reply, I'm going to mark the answer by @juancarlos as correct as his solution will return the exact matches (all criteria) whereas this solution will return an 'empty' result for all entries that match "myId":"1222222" even if $elemMatch does not return anything.